# Argparse - accessing multiple arguments at once

Tags: python, argparse

my application uses a database, so when adding a new element (from command line) I want to check if this one is already in the database, what I do with the "type" parameter of add_argument:

```
def check_uniq(project_name):
    if Project.exists(project_name):
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(
    return project_name
```

this is working just fine, however to make think easier to the final user I'd like to add a `--force` option to my arguments so this variable is tested and delete before to add and in this case do note raise the argument. How can I access within the check_uniq to the --force option ?

Comment: Are the parsed arguments available as a global? You can also pass in the `Namespace` object into the function..

Answer (score 2):

Test if the option is set in the same `if` stamement:

```
def check_uniq(project_name, options):
    if Project.exists(project_name) and not options.force:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError('Project already exists')
    return project_name
```

where `options` takes the `Namespace` instance returned by `parser.parse_args()`.

Unfortunately, you cannot verify this until *all* arguments have been parsed, you cannot use this function as a `type` parameter, because the `--force` option can be specified anywhere on the command line, before *or* after the option that specifies your project name.

If you require that `--force` is listed *before* any projects on your command line, you *could* use a custom [`action`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#action) instead; a custom action is passed the `namespace` object as parsed *so far*:

```
class UniqueProjectAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, value, option_string=None):
        if Project.exists(value) and not namespace.force:
            raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError('Project already exists')
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)
```

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the `type` function is to convert an argument string to some other kind of object (`int`, `float`, `file`).  It does not have access to the `namespace` or other attributes of the parser.  Indirectly it has access to the global state, such as when trying to open a file in `FileType`.

The `action` has access to the `namespace`, though usually that is for the purpose of setting a value (attribute).  It can check the values of other attributes, but that ends up limiting the order in which attributes are set (e.g. `--force` has to come before `database`).

You can also check `namespace` attributes after `parse_args`.  You can still used the `argparse` error mechanism by calling `parser.error('your message')`.  It may be easier to check values at this stage, since you don't have to worry about the order of the strings in `sys.argv`.