# python argparse: how to use other parsed argument as parameter at calling function in type keyword?

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to create an user interface using argparse module.

One of the argument need to be converted, so I use the type keyword:

```
add_argument('positional', ..., type=myfunction)
```

and there is another optional argument:

```
add_argument('-s', dest='switch', ...)
```

in addition, I have

```
parsed_argument=parse_args()
```

However, in `myfunction`, I hope I can use an additional parameter to control the behavior, which is the optional argument above, i.e.

```
def myfunction(positional, switch=parsed_argument.switch): 
     ...
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Argparse - accessing multiple arguments at once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18657151/argparse-accessing-multiple-arguments-at-once)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here... Can you show an example of what you want your commands look like? Are you trying to do some git-like behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: You can’t. The arguments are parsed separately, and there is no real guarantee that some order is maintained. Instead of putting your logic into the argument type, just store it as a string and do your stuff after parsing the command line:

```
parser.add_argument('positional')
parser.add_argument('-s', '--switch')

args = parser.parse_args()

myfunction(args.positional, switch=args.switch)
```

Comment: Then how can I raise an argparse-like exception, such as `error: unrecognized arguments`, in stead of print out the Trackback?

Comment: @user1824372 You can throw argparse errors using [`parser.error(message)`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.error).

Comment: Nice, that is what I want. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I did understand correctly what you want to achieve, but if what you want to do is something that looks like:

```
myprog.py cmd1 --switcha
myprog.py cmd2 --switchb
```

yes you can, you need to use subparsers. I wrote a good example of it for a little [PoC I wrote to access stackoverflow's API from CLI](https://github.com/guyzmo/pystackoverflow/blob/master/stackoverflow/cli.py). The whole logic is a bit long to put thoroughly here, but mainly the idea is:

1. create your parser using `parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(...)`
2. create the subparsers using `subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(...)`
3. add the commands with things like `subparser.add_parser('mycommand', help='Its only a command').set_defaults(func=mycmd_fn) where
4. `mycmd_fn` takes `args` as parameters where you have all the switches you issued to the command!

the difference from what you ask, is that you'll need one function per command, and not one function with the `positional` argument as first argument. But you can leverage that easily by having mycmd_fn being like: `mycmd_fn = lambda *args: myfunction('mycmd', *args)`

HTH

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> type= can take any callable that takes a single string argument and returns the converted value:

Python functions like `int` and `float` are good examples of a type function should be like.  `int` takes a string and returns a number.  If it can't convert the string it raises a `ValueError`.    Your function could do the same.  `argparse.ArgumentTypeError` is another option.  `argparse` isn't going to pass any optional arguments to it.  Look at the code for `argparse.FileType` to see a more elaborate example of a custom `type`.

`action` is another place where you can customize behavior.  The documentation has an example of a custom Action.  Its arguments include the `namespace`, the object where the parser is collecting the values it will return to you.  This object contains any arguments have already been set.  In theory your `switch` value will be available there - if it occurs first.

There are many SO answers that give custom `Actions`.

Subparsers are another good way of customizing the handling of arguments.

Often it is better to check for the interaction of arguments after `parse_args`.  In your case 'switch' could occur after the positional and still have effect.  And `argparse.Error` lets you use the `argparse` error mechanism (e.g. displaying the usage)